# How to refresh LWC component using getRelatedListRecords when related record edited

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, refreshapex, relatedrecord

I have a component rendering a list of records related to the record on which the component is displayed using `getRelatedListRecords` (Beta).

```js
   //Get Related List Records Info
   @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
     parentRecordId: "$recordId",enter code here
     relatedListId: "Karere__r",
     fields: KARERE_FIELDS
   })
   listRecordInfo(result) {
     console.log("getRelatedListRecords Karere: " + JSON.stringify(result));
     if (result.data) {
       this.karereList = result.data.records;
       this.error = undefined;
     } else if (result.error) {
       this.error = error;
       this.relatedListRecords = undefined;
     }
   }
```

When I add an additional related record (or edit an existing one) I would like the related list to update accordingly... I'm inserting new related records like a so:

```js
   handleSend() {
 
     let messageField = this.template.querySelector("lightning-input");
 
     addKarere({
       contactId: this.recordId,
       koreroId: this.koreroId,
       message: messageField.value
     })
       .then((result) => {
         console.log('Add Karere Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
         getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: result.Id}]);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         this.error = error;
         console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
       });
   }
```

Tried variations of `getRecordNotifyChange`, `refreshApex`, and `eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available yet, unfortunately. If you can get by with creating/modifying the records via lws functions (createRecord,updateRecord), I find storing a reference to the records returned by getRelatedListRecords and just pushing created record references and replacing updated ones works unless you specifically need to pull changes made by other users.